# AppCompatActivity cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm building an app using Java and Cordova, but I have come across this problem  -

[image]

In the code I have:

```
    public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{

    private AppCompatActivity appCompat;
```

then later:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        //Initiate Paypal service
        appCompat = new AppCompatActivity(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        appCompat.startService(intent);
    }
```

Which is where the problem is, but I can't understand why it can't be applied to the class? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AppCompatActivity constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#AppCompatActivity()) does not take any parameters. Remove "this".

```
appCompat = new AppCompatActivity();
```